# how to get latitude and longitude values on each levelplot in combined plot

Tags: r, lattice

I'm plotting multiple levelplots together. I'm using the following code. however I'm not getting the coordinates on the x and y axis. how do I get that?
stack_hist is my stack of rasters to plot.

```
library(lattice)

levelplot(stack_hist, main = "", 
          xlab = list("Longitude", cex = 1), ylab = list("Latitude", cex = 1),
          layout = c(2, 2), names.attr = c("A", "B", "C"),
          par.strip.text = list(cex = 1, lines = 1),
          colorkey = list(at = c(seq(0, 1200, by = 200), Inf),
                          labels =  c("0", "200", "400", "600", "800", "1000", "1200", "Inf"),
                          col = my_colors),
          par.settings = list(strip.border = list(col = 'transparent'),
                              strip.background = list(col = 'transparent'),
                              axis.line = list(col = 'transparent'),
                              panel.background = list(col = 'white')),
          scales = list(draw = F, x = list(cex = 1), y = list(cex = 1)),
          col.regions = my_colors,
          at = my.at) +
  layer(sp.polygons(SHP, col = 'grey90'))
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?